# Should I encrypt a GUID passed by URL-parameters?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, security, encryption

We are creating a Silverlight application and need to have a few parameters pass in with the URL from calling site.

example:   http://oursite.com/index.aspx?test=d53ae99b-06a0-4ba7-81ed-4556adc532b2

We want to give the calling website 'test' string that links back to the GUID of our table which tells the Silverlight application what it's task is when they arrive. We also use this GUID for authentication on our application among other things.

The GUID are as such:

1. d53ae99b-06a0-4ba7-81ed-4556adc532b2
2. 8354b838-99b3-4b4c-bb07-7cf68620072e

Encrypted, the values are much longer:

1. l5GyhPWSBUw8KdD+TpWJOsoOFDF0LzmGzd4uufLx+v/d3eByGZ6zPcRjvCRMG2tg
2. WVMN7B0FPa18/Q7+U4njb5AOKnx6Ga9xoAsvCET6MyjM5TV6dO86OexaCXDiXaES

My question is, with security in mind, should we give them the GUID encrypted or like it is, unencrypted?

Does it matter?

What is everyone's experience with this type of parameter passing?

Comment: My question would be: why are your encrypted values so much longer? I don't really see a need for them to increase in size - you are doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In matters of encryption, the key is to define your security context. What might someone be able to do if they had access to the original GUIDs? If they couldn't do anything hazardous, there's no point encrypting, and it's generally best not to encrypt. If there's any security risk posed by this information being publicly available, you'd better encrypt it.

Since you say:

> We also use this guid for authentication on our application among other things

... I'm guessing you'll want to encrypt. But you may want to re-think your authentication strategy. It's often best to use time-tested, well-accepted methods for things like authentication and encryption, since you can be relatively certain that there aren't unknown exploits.

Comment: That pretty much was our way of thinking. We don't need to encrypt it since even if they did obtain it, it would be useless to them. Btw, we are only using the guid to look up the state in the database which expires after a period of time. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I'd still be concerned about looking up the state.  At any time a hacker could steal someone else's GUID and switch the URL to use theirs.  The application would then load using someone else's state.  If you use that state to maintain any type of security info, the hacker could elevate their permissions.

Comment: Just bear in mind that each request needs to start with, "Does the currently-authenticated user have rights to do X on Guid Y?" That's why I'm saying you don't want to use the GUID for authentication. As Tony says, if someone else can steal a Guid and have the application think they're that other user, then you have a security hole.